# How to show popup on mouse hover of marker in ngx-mapbox-gl

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I am currently showing markers and popups on click of markers. We have a requirement now to show popups on hover.

my template is like below :

```
<mgl-map #map1 
    [style]="'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'" 
    [zoom]="[4]"
    [maxZoom]="maxZoom"
    [center]="[-95.7129, 37.0902]"
    [fitBounds]="bounds"
    [fitBoundsOptions]="boundsOptions">
    <mgl-control mglNavigation [showCompass]="false"></mgl-control>
    <ngContainer *ngFor="let deal of unlockedDeals">
        <mgl-marker #myMarker [lngLat]="lngLat[deal.deal_id]">
            <div class="marker"></div>
            <span><b>{{ deal.deal_name }}</b></span>
        </mgl-marker>
        <mgl-popup [marker]="myMarker" class="" [closeButton]="true" [closeOnClick]="false"
            [anchor]="'top'">
            <div class="marker-popup-details">
             custom popup
            </div>
        </mgl-popup>
    </ngContainer>
</mgl-map>
```

no code relevant to map in component.

Comment: did you find away to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a marker with `mouseout` and `mouseover` events and a popup as such:

```html
<mgl-popup *ngIf="hoverFeature" [lngLat]="hoverFeature.geometry.coordinates" [closeButton]="false">
    <span>{{hoverFeature.properties.title}}</span>
</mgl-popup>
<mgl-marker [lngLat]="otherFeature.geometry.coordinates" anchor="bottom">
    <div (mouseover)="hoverFeature = otherFeature" (mouseout)="hoverFeature = null">
        {{otherFeature.properties.title}}
    </div>
</mgl-marker>
```